# How do I configure my router to allow a tor connection into onionshare?

Tags: tails, firewall

I want to onionshare a file from a pc running tails that is behind a firewall. The firewall currently forwards a couple of ports to a webserver on a different device, but blocks all others. Everything looks OK, but then if I try to access the shared file from a browser I get an error message

This site can’t be reached, page may be down or site moved, ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED

Experimenting further - the TOR browser on the same machine can see the shared file but the TOR browswer on another machine cannot. Sharing from another machine (using the latest onionshare) its files can be seen by itself and by the tails machine.

I notice the Tails version of onionshare is not the latest...

Answer (score 1):

My Tails hadn't upgraded to the latest version - the version I was running used the old style, short, onion addresses.